# how to resolve object Null error?

Tags: asp.net, session, object, null

I have a situation where i am assigning some value to a session. I have a situation in which that code is calling repeatedly. some times this code throws error of object null. I am not getting why this is happening while i am assign value to it.My code is

```
  if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Cache"] == null)
            {
                CreateChanhe();
                DataTable dtcache= HttpContext.Current.Cache["HNS Connection"] as DataTable; //CreateConnectString(CCMMUtility.Encryptdata(txtPin.Text));
                string sqlFilter = "Sp = '" + classses.DecryptString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Cookies"].Values["sp"].ToString(), classses.SP) + "'";
                DataRow[] dr = dtcache.Select(sqlFilter);
                if (dr.Length > 0)
                {
                    String[] Con = new String[2];
                    Con[0] = dr[0][0].ToString();
                    Con[1] = dr[0][1].ToString();
                    sp= Con[1]; 
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] = dr[0][2].ToString();
                }
            }
```

When i am try to do "Add watch" while debugging its says the "value" has some value but the **HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"]** is null. Can some let me know why this is happening.

Actually i am creating a cache then fills session from that cache. this is based on my requirement.

Comment: This code line seems all right to me, I guess there should be some other code line which is causing this bug. You should elaborate more.

Comment: Hi,

You might be checking HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] value when you have not assigned any value of session variable.

Could be please post you code so that I can analysed more.

Comment: I have edited the Code please review.

Comment: What does the stack trace say? The code you have posted is where you are assigning the value. The stack trace for the error will tell where the exception is happening. That might shed some light...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `dr[0][2]` is null so when you call `.ToString()` on it you are getting a NRE.

Comment: I have checked its value its not null it has some value. But the HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] is null

Comment: @Visions from what method/function you are executing code. My guess! your code is executed in application_start or such events where user request is not made.

Comment: I think that if this was the case (Application_Start) he would have gotten a different exception. For example if you attempt to use HttpContext specific stuff in Application_Start under IIS7+ running in integrated pipeline mode you will get a specific exception, not NRE. For me there are 2 possibilities: either the one I already expressed in my answer or he is running this code in a background thread where obviously he has not access to sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the HttpContext.Current is null? If so wrap a null check around it like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
 if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Cache"] == null)
            {
                CreateChanhe();
                DataTable dtcache= HttpContext.Current.Cache["HNS Connection"] as                        DataTable; //CreateConnectString(CCMMUtility.Encryptdata(txtPin.Text));
                string sqlFilter = "Sp = '" + classses.DecryptString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Cookies"].Values["sp"].ToString(), classses.SP) + "'";
                DataRow[] dr = dtcache.Select(sqlFilter);
                if (dr.Length > 0)
                {
                    String[] Con = new String[2];
                    Con[0] = dr[0][0].ToString();
                    Con[1] = dr[0][1].ToString();
                    sp= Con[1]; 
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] = dr[0][2].ToString();
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] is returning null?

Comment: where i am assign some value to session.

Comment: To solve this you will need to show us the stack trace or the error page.